# wxpython - Return an Input Variable from another Frame

Tags: wxpython

How can I, in one panel that is in one frame, reference an input variable that is in another panel in another frame?

I basically want to create an 'Options' tab in the menubar of my wxpython gui, that when clicked on, opens a new frame that allows the user to change some variables. However, when I try to reference those variables later, I get
    AttributeError: type object 'OptionsPanel' has no attribute 'Input1'

I have both panels and both frames defined as classes.
Here is my complete code:

```py
import wx
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(200,300))
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu = wx.Menu()
        m_options = menu.Append(wx.ID_EDIT, "&Options", "Options")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOptions, m_options)
        menuBar.Append(menu, "&Options")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        panel=MainPanel(self)
    def OnOptions(self, event):
        frame = OptionsFrame("Options Frame")
        frame.Show()
class OptionsFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(200,200))    
        panel=OptionsPanel(self)
class OptionsPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Input Value", pos=(40,60))
        self.Input1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="1.0", pos=(80,80), size=(60,-1))
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="GO", pos=(60,100))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick,self.button)
    def OnClick(self,event):
        MyVariable= OptionsPanel.Input1.GetValue() #This won't work!
        print dt0
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = MainFrame("Multiple Frames Attempt")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the OnClick method in class MainPanel is referencing the class OptionsPanel instead of referencing the instantiation of the class OptionsPanel ('panel') in class OptionsFrame.

```
import wx
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(200,300))
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu = wx.Menu()
        m_options = menu.Append(wx.ID_EDIT, "&Options", "Options")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOptions, m_options)
        menuBar.Append(menu, "&Options")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        panel=MainPanel(self)
        self.options_frame = None
    def OnOptions(self, event):
        self.options_frame = OptionsFrame("Options Frame")
        self.options_frame.Show()
    def GetInput1Value(self):
        if self.options_frame is not None:
            return(self.options_frame.options_panel.Input1.GetValue())
        else:
            return('None')
class OptionsFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(200,200))    
        self.options_panel=OptionsPanel(self)
class OptionsPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Input Value", pos=(40,60))
        self.Input1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="1.0", pos=(80,80), size=(60,-1))
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent_frame = parent
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="GO", pos=(60,100))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick,self.button)
    def OnClick(self,event):
        MyVariable= self.parent_frame.GetInput1Value()
        print MyVariable
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = MainFrame("Multiple Frames Attempt")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks David, would you have a recommendation on what changes I would need in the code to fix this?

Comment: I acknowledge this is not very pythonic, but see my edited answer.

Comment: Do these changes to your code make sense? You see that OnClick in class MainPanel now has access to the Input1 TextCtrl?

Comment: Nice! It works! Sorry I had a Holiday break... Well I would like to be able to enter the number in the options frame, have an OK button that closes the option frame, and still be able to reference that value later without the options frame open...